# Merge Objects With Same JSON Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm having some troubles merging an array of JSON objects together by key. Would anyone have a good solution to this using just Javascript?

```
{
    "code": "12345",
    "error": "12345 error 1"
},
{
    "code": "12345",
    "error": "12345 error 2"
},
{
    "code": "67890",
    "error": "67890 error 1"
},
{
    "code": "67890",
    "error": "67890 error 2"
},
{
    "code": "67890",
    "error": "67890 error 3"
},
{
    "code": "67890",
    "error": "67890 error 4"
},
{
    "code": "67890",
    "error": "67890 error 5"
},
{
    "code": "12092",
    "error": "12092 error 1"
},
{
    "code": "12092",
    "error": "12092 error 2"
}
```

Should be transformed to

```
{
    "code": "12345",
    "error": "12345 error 1, 12345 error 2"
},
{
    "code": "67890",
    "error": "67890 error 1, 67890 error 2, 67890 error 3, 67890 error 4, 67890 error 5"
},
{
    "code": "12092",
    "error": "12092 error 1, 12092 error 2"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've racked my brain over this for a long time and just cant seem to get it down.

Comment: please post the code that you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array `reduce` to create the new merged array of objects. Inside the callback function check if the accumulator array have an object which already have the `code`. For this use `findIndex`. If the code matches then update the `error`. Else push the current object in the accumulator

```js
const data = [{"code":"12345","error":"12345 error 1"},{"code":"12345","error":"12345 error 2"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 1"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 2"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 3"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 4"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 5"},{"code":"12092","error":"12092 error 1"},{"code":"12092","error":"12092 error 2"}];

let mergedData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.code === curr.code;
  })
  if (findIndex === -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  } else {
    acc[findIndex].error += ', ' + curr.error
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(mergedData)
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long. This solution worked great for me!! Than you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you could do somethign like this.

Idea is to first regroup everything with the Array#reduce and Map, and then to transform the data to the output you seek using Array#map.

```js
const data = [{"code":"12345","error":"12345 error 1"},{"code":"12345","error":"12345 error 2"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 1"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 2"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 3"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 4"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 5"},{"code":"12092","error":"12092 error 1"},{"code":"12092","error":"12092 error 2"}];

const res = Array.from(
  data.reduce((a,{code, error})=>{
    return a.set(code, [error].concat(a.get(code)||[]))
  }, new Map())
).map(([code, error])=>({code, error: error.join(",")}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer using Reduce and checking for the existing object key is perfect.

Here's another method of doing this using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and other ES6 syntax (`for...of`) that I think is easy to read and just another interesting approach:

```js
const data = [{"code":"12345","error":"12345 error 1"},{"code":"12345","error":"12345 error 2"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 1"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 2"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 3"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 4"},{"code":"67890","error":"67890 error 5"},{"code":"12092","error":"12092 error 1"},{"code":"12092","error":"12092 error 2"}];

// Define a new empty Map.
const map = new Map();

// Loop through all data objects.
for (const dataEntry of data) {

  // Check if we've already added this to our map; if not, add blank entry.
  if (!map.has(dataEntry.code)) {
      map.set(dataEntry.code, {code: dataEntry.code,error:[]});
  }

  // Append to the error property.
  const mapEntry = map.get(dataEntry.code);
  mapEntry.error.push(dataEntry.error);

}

// Flatten the error entries to be a single String instead of an Array.
for (const entry of map.values()) {
  entry.error = entry.error.join(', ');
}

const output = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Actually, reduce isn't *perfect* many people look down on it. It's often preferable to use a simple for loop instead of reduce. +1

Comment: I agree @kemicofa. I've strayed away from lots of clever map/reduce blocks in favor of syntax like the example above. Map and reduce are still used in my code when appropriate, but I find this easier to come back to at a later date and grok quickly.